# Git: move a branch to make it point to another

Tags: git, git-branch

I had the following situation:

```
-----O
     |
   master
   branch1
```

then I had to make some changes to master:

```
 -----O-----O-----O
      |           |
   branch1      master
```

now I want branch1 to be at the same point of master (and therefore to contain the commits I made):

```
-----O-----O-----O
                 |
               master
               branch1
```

I don't know if a merge would be the correct way to achieve this.
what steps should I take?

EDIT: also consider that I have uncommitted changes that should be committed on branch1 after branch1 is up to date with master. so I need the current changes to be left untouched to be committed later on branch1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `branch1` references a commit that is an *ancestor* of `master`, a merge operation won't result in a merge commit; instead, Git will simply move the `branch1` reference forward so that it references the same commit as `master`. This is called a [*fast-forward*](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_fast_forward) merge.

From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging):

> When you try to merge one commit with a
>   commit that can be reached by following the first commit’s history,
>   Git simplifies things by moving the pointer forward because there is
>   no divergent work to merge together – this is called a “fast-forward.”

So, in your case, you can simply say:

```
git checkout branch1
git merge master
```

which will make `branch1` point to the same commit as `master`.

**Update:** note that you need to have a [*clean* working directory](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_clean) before doing the merge. If you have uncommitted changes in `branch1` (i.e. you have a [*dirty* working directory](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_dirty)), you should first store them away in the [stash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) by using the [`git-stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) command:

```
git stash save --include-untracked -m "Work in progress"
```

Once your changes are saved and your working directory clean, you can proceed with the merge. Afterwards, you can restore the files from the stash by saying:

```
git stash pop
```

which will put those files back in the working directory and remove them from the stash. At that point, you can choose to commit them in any numbers of commits.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have uncommitted changes that should be committed on branch1, but after branch1 is up to date with master. will the method you have proposed leave the current changes untouched to be committed later on branch1?

Comment: No, but you can stash them before doing the merge. See my updated answer.

Comment: ok I see, so I checkout branch1, stash the changes, merge branch1 into master and unstash right?

Comment: Almost – you merge `master` into `branch1`; you want to bring `branch1` to the same commit as `master`, so you merge `master` _to_ `branch1`. Think about it this way: when using `git merge`, the branch you're on is the _destination_ (i.e. _to_ `branch1`) while the branch you specify is the _source_ (i.e. the _from_ `master`).

Answer (score 0):

In this simple case, you can do it the simple way:

```
git branch -f branch1 master
```

From `git help branch`:

```
git branch [--set-upstream | --track | --no-track] [-l] [-f] <branchname> [<start-point>]
```

EDIT: to keep uncommitted changes:

```
git stash
git checkout master
git branch -f branch1 master
git checkout branch1
git stash pop
```

The uncommitted changes will now again be uncommitted (or unadded, depending on what they were before).

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have uncommitted changes that should be committed on branch1, but after branch1 is up to date with master. will the method you have proposed leave the current changes untouched to be committed later on branch1?

Answer (score 0):

This looks a job for rebase, so I would do the following:

```
git commit -m 'your work on branch 1'    # from branch1
git rebase master                        # also from branch1
```

This will pull in the new commits from `master` into `branch1`, and then replays your commit on top of the commits from `master`.

Functionally speaking, merging `master` into `branch1` should also be OK, but you might not maintain the resolution the two commits, instead ending up with a single merge commit.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have uncommitted changes that should be committed on branch1, but after branch1 is up to date with master. will the method you have proposed leave the current changes untouched to be committed later on branch1?

Comment: @JacopoGrassi No issues, just commit your work then do the rebase.

Comment: oh wait, but this will bring the new commit to be on master too (I guess), but I want them to be only on branch1

Comment: No it won't.  It will make a commit only on `branch1`.

Answer (score 0):

If your working directory is clean (otherwise do a 'stash'), you are in a special case where 'rebase', 'merge' and 'reset --hard' do exactly what you want to do...

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have uncommitted changes that should be committed on branch1, but after branch1 is up to date with master. will the method you have proposed leave the current changes untouched to be committed later on branch1?

Comment: In this case, that's a lot better to commit first (that way, if you mess around you will always be to fix and retry), then rebase and if you're not completely satisfied with your commit, amend it or at last 'reset --soft'